# Disable Uninstall button in android manageapplication

Tags: android

How to disable the Uninstall button in android management applications ?

If i once install the app in mobile device, if any end user want to uninstall that app, then he not able to uninstall it.

Comment: You really, like **really** don't want your users to uninstall your app do you?? ;-)

Comment: yes.. really? please help me in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make your application uninstallable (well... You can't really if the user is using a rooted phone) would be to install it directly in Android bundle, pushing it via ADB (while rooted) to the

> /system/app

directory...

Then, it's in anyway possible for a dev with standard access to the users phone.

Comment: please send me how to make an application as permanent in android

Comment: i am also interested for get solution

Comment: please tell me how to disable the clear data button in android manage applications.....