# Disable clear data and uninstall update /system/app/

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have an application that comes baked onto about 10 un-rooted device OS's. Located in /system/app. 
We're trying to update the application and prevent the users from uninstalling a critical update or clear the data. How could we go about disabling the "Clear Data" And "Uninstall Update" in the manage applications menu.

Comment: I would like to add that this is a non-android-market / Google Play application, its a enterprise APK. It comes pre-installed on the device. We just need to make sure it can update and never revert back to the original APK (unless factory reset).

Comment: This cannot be done from the app itself, I don't think. If your OS has been modified, you should be able to do it from source modifications.

Comment: I've been reading since we're installed in the system/aps folder its possible since baked APKS cannot be uninstalled (currently we're a baked APK) but they can uninstall our updates. 
This here was some advice http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html
but still looking for more answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351860/disable-uninstall-button-in-android-manageapplication
Here is where I read about the system/apps

Comment: There are apps in market such as AntiTheftDroid which does this,but its still a mystery for me.